# Libgdx does not get screen resolution correctly on Android 4

Tags: android, libgdx

I have Sony Xperia P with 960*540 resolution and with Android 4.04.
Libgdx 0.9.7 (December, 2012) detects it's resolution
as 569*320.
The code is here:

```
       public void create() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
        SCREEN_WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        SCREEN_HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
```

On all other devices that I tried, it works okay.
So what to do?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you used the proper minSdkVersion (give a try to 4) and targetSdkVersion (try 12 or 15) in your manifest file?

Comment: I use 3.2 minSdk. Wow! Should I use 4? Will it work on devices with Android 2.1? Thanks!

Comment: I tried Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size); But compilation error: getSize is red. Deprecated display.getWidth() is also red.

Comment: I tried SDK 4.2. But the same red errors on getSize. Hmm... My Java is 1.6. I've heard that 1.7 has problems with Android

Comment: Maybe something wrong with Class:   public class MyActivity extends AndroidApplication implements IActivityRequestHandler

Comment: When running on Android in libgdx, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() and Gdx.graphics.getHeight() are set in AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged() which implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer. You could try creating your own renderer to eliminate whether the problem lies with the phone or with libgdx. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html#onSurfaceChanged(javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10, int, int) for more details on what you'd need to do.

Comment: Ah! Playing with SDK does not work. I need a code:Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); Point size = new Point(); display.getSize(size); Such code works only in
"public class MyActivity extends Activity".

But I run Libgdx in the following class:
"public class MyActivity extends AndroidApplication implements IActivityRequestHandler"

Should I start Activity class and then AndroidApplication class?
Or there are other ways?

Comment: Rod Hyde: frankly I could not understand this page. I see width as input parameter, but not as output there... Can you suggest some libgdx way to solve the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you a solid answer because I do not own a Sony Xperia P. I have tested LibGDX on a number of devices and have not encountered this issue yet. My only suggestion is to update LibGDX to the [latest nightly build](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/) and see if they have fixed it. You can also use their [update tool](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/dist/gdx-setup-ui.jar) to do this as well.

The way libGDX development works, the nightly builds are actually very stable. Since the framework is actively developed, I would be surprised if something as critical as this has slipped through. If using the latest nightly build does not work, I would suggest putting in a bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/list). They are usually pretty quick about fixing issues.